# Is there a role that grants read only access to the entire sitecore backend?

Tags: sitecore-client, user-management

I need to create a user for an external web agency. They should have read only access but to the entire backend. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new role and assign rights like on bellow image:

[image]

This role should be member of the role: **Sitecore Limited Content Editor** which limits the amount of Content Editor functionality provided by the Sitecore Client Authoring role (which is still required for users given this role). If you don't assign this role to your custom role you can not access Sitecore.

When a content author is assigned to **Sitecore Limited Content Editor**, the author only have access to the Home, Review, and Publish tabs on the Content Editor ribbon and have no access to Copy, Move, or Sort from the item's right-click menu.

You need to create a user based on your custom role.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The user needs to be granted read only access to everything in the backend and not just the content editor. How would I accomplish that?